# remove x 0 in a string using php

Tags: php, regex

I have values for the dimensions of the product the data of product is added via admin panel using import feature there are lots of products so doing it manually is a headache so on the front end if the value in 0 and space for any of the dimension values, then have to exclude it without the value at all. Ex. if the value is 1 x 1 x 0 (L X W X H) or 1 x 1 x (L X W X H), then record the value on the site as 1 x 1 (L X W). I have tried here is the values in the table

Size : 9.06 x 5.12 x 0 (LxWxH)

I have tried using str_replace function but the problem is that how will i gonna remove the symbol of the relatable value it could be 1 x 0 x 1 (L X W X H) so it should be like this 1 x 1 (L X H)

```
`$ship_weight_attr = $ship_weight_values[$size_pos];

 $ship_weight_attr = str_replace(' x 0', '', $ship_weight_attr);
 $ship_weight_attr = str_replace(' x ', '', $ship_weight_attr);
```

`

Now I am looking to get a better solution so I can get rid of the unusual values

Comment: You can find the part in parens, and split the string into two parts ("1 x 1 x 0" and "L X W X H").  Now you can explode the two based on the X, and run through the two arrays in parallel, keeping the ones you want.

Comment: let suppose if I explode using explode(' ' , $var) i cannot separate into 2 pairs or am i missing anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This what you need?  It's probably longer than it needs to be but easy to understand.

```
function formatDimensions($value) {
    $aDimensions = explode('x', $value);

    $aDescription = [];
    $aValue = [];

    if (($aDimensions[0] ?? 0) > 0) {
        $aDescription[] = 'L';
        $aValue[] = trim($aDimensions[0]);
    }

    if (($aDimensions[1] ?? 0) > 0) {
        $aDescription[] = 'W';
        $aValue[] = trim($aDimensions[1]);
    }

    if (($aDimensions[2] ?? 0) > 0) {
        $aDescription[] = 'H';
        $aValue[] = trim($aDimensions[2]);
    }

    $description = join(' x ', $aDescription);
    $value = join(' x ', $aValue);

    return $value . ' (' . $description . ')';

} //funct

echo formatDimensions('1 x 1 x 0');
echo '<br>';
echo formatDimensions('1 x 2 x ');
echo '<br>';
echo formatDimensions('1 x 3 x 4');
```

This outputs:

1 x 1 (L x W)

1 x 2 (L x W)

1 x 3 x 4 (L x W x H)

Comment: Or like no spaces between lxwxh ?? will it still work right

Comment: If you have spaces in there sometimes, you could use $aDimensions = explode('x', $value); and trim() the values.  Hope that helps

Comment: I changed the code to deal with the optional spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a regex solution that will handle any order:

```
<?php

function process($s)
{
    $exp = "/([\d.]*)\s*[xX]\s*([\d.]*)\s*[xX]\s*([\d.]*)\s*\(([LWH])[xX]([LWH])[xX]([LWH])\)/";

    preg_match( $exp, $s, $matches );
    print_r($matches);
    $one = array();
    $two = array();
    for( $i = 0; $i < 3; $i++ )
    {
        if( $matches[$i+1] != 0 )
        {
            $one[] = $matches[$i+1];
            $two[] = $matches[$i+4];
        }
    }
    return implode(" x ",$one) . " (" . implode("X",$two) . ")";
}

echo process("9.06 x 5.12 x 0 (LxWxH)");
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 9.06 x 5.12 x 0 (LxWxH)
    [1] => 9.06
    [2] => 5.12
    [3] => 0
    [4] => L
    [5] => W
    [6] => H
)
9.06 x 5.12 (LXW)
```

Comment: I liked your approach